# Confirmation to pause form submit until Ok has beenpushed

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, dialog

I have a form that a confirmation dialog pops up (do you want to continue) right now it pops up but the form is being sent to my controller at the same time, which begins processing regardless if you hit yes or no.  How do I pause the form submit until after the javascript confirmation has been shown/selected.

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Process", "Home", FormMethod.Post, 
 new { id ="MyForm" })) {  
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name); 
    // other form controls...
    <input id="Submit" type="submit" value="Apply Changes" /> 
 }
```

javascript: (using jquery-ui)

```
 $(function () {
        $("#Confirm").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            buttons: {
                "Ok": function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    $('#MyForm').submit();
                    return true;
                },
                Cancel: function() {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    event.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });

        $("#Submit").click(function () {
            $("#Confirm").dialog("open");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prevent the default action immediately, then trigger the submit on the ok button press.

```
 $(function () {
    $("#Confirm").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons: {
            "Ok": function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                $('#MyForm')[0].submit();
            },
            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    });

    $("#MyForm").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#Confirm").dialog("open");
    });
});
```

Comment: Although this will work, why have a submit button if you just take away the functionality of that submit button?

Comment: This isn't taking away the functionality of the submit button? Doing it this way actually *preserves* default behavior by allowing the form to be submitted by either pressing enter on an input or clicking the submit button, both of which will get a confirm dialog. If you instead use a button click to do the work, pressing enter on an input will bypass the confirm dialog.

Comment: Sure it does, you call e.preventDefault() which cancels the event and the submission of the form. Then you just open the modal? Why not have a regular button open the modal and if the user clicks "OK", submit the form using $('#MyForm').submit()?

Comment: Because if you don't prevent the default action pressing enter will bypass your confirmation dialog.

Comment: Preserving the default pressing "enter" is a good argument for this approach. +1

Comment: @Rob not only that - but moving the button outside the form still doesn't handle when a user hits enter inside the form.  Hit enter while the form has focus in this example [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4Xutr/)

Comment: That does the trick! Yeah I didn't want to have the button outside just in case they had js disabled, then nothing would happen. This way if they don't have js enabled, they just don't get the confirmation

Answer (score 2):

Move the `submit` button outside of the form and change it to a regular `<input type="button"/>`.

Your modal "OK" function does the submit for you, so you don't need a submit button in the form.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Process", "Home", FormMethod.Post, 
 new { id ="MyForm" })) {  
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name); 
    // other form controls...

 }
<input id="Submit" type="button" value="Apply Changes" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the "onsubmit" event of the form itself and return either `true` or `false` if you want it to actually submit data or not.